# Password Change Expect Script

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, tcl, expect

first time caller, long time listener, I have a question centering around an expect script and changing the password on several hosts. I do not have any issue getting the expect script to rotate or change the password, the issue i am having is the expects scripts ability to handle multiple 'expects'. I need to account for 4 things, our environment is borked and dumb - please bear with me.

1. Account is fine, password needs rotated -- this works
2. Account is expired, password needs changed -- this works
3. Account is already using new password -- not built in yet
4. Account is locked -- not built in

My script is looping through a list of hosts and logging in, I want it to do one of a few things -- when it logs in, if the account is expired it will expect certain things and change the password, this works. If this does not come up and the script logs in fine with the old password, just execute the passwd command and change password. THe problem I am having right now is getting the two things to work together correctly.

If the host list contains a mix, where the account is expired and in good standing I want to be able to loop through and handle each situation appropriately then log it. Right now, if i put in some test hosts (4 to 5) where the account is expired and fine, the script works if the last hosts are expired. But will not work if the first host is expired then has to move to a new host.

Here is the code below, I have scoured the internet for knowledge and nothing matching this has come up.

I want to be able to say, if the expect value == (current UNIX password) then do this, if the old password is being used go ahead and change to new password...really struggling to get it working together.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect



set timeout 10
set user userAccount
set password oldPassword
set new_password newPassword


set f [open "input.txt"]
set hosts [read $f]
close $f


## need to say if the expected value is "(current) UNIX password: then do this"
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
    expect "Password:" 
    send "$password\r"
        expect { 
            "(current) UNIX password:" {send $password\r; exp_continue}
            "New password:" {send $new_password\r; exp_continue}
            "Retype new password:" {send $new_password\r; exp_continue}
            "~]$" {close}
}
    send "echo -e '$password\n$new_password\n$new_password' | passwd\r"
    expect "~]$" {close}
}
```

Comment: It's possible that you login, are forced to change the password, then you get to the `echo ... | passwd` and the old password is no longer valid. You might want to set a flag if you change the password during login, and only run the passwd command if the flag is not set.

Comment: how would i set that flag?

Comment: before the expect command `set login_pw_change false`, in the "retype" body add `set login_pw_change true`, then `if {$login_pw_change} {send "echo -e ... | passwd\r"}`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the easiest solution is to make a small change to your first expect command:

```
expect { 
    "(current) UNIX password:" {send $password\r; exp_continue}
    "New password:" {send $new_password\r; exp_continue}
    "Retype new password:" {send $new_password\r}
    "~]$" {send "echo -e '$password\n$new_password\n$new_password' | passwd\r"}
}
expect "~]$" {close}
```

The crucial part is that there's no exp_continue after the second time you send the new password. It will then break out of the first expect command and only match the prompt of the second expect command. If the password hasn't expired, the prompt inside the first expect command will be found. So that's where you can run the passwd command.

---

With your other wishes added, the loop body could look something like this:

```
spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
expect "assword: " 
send "$password\r"
expect {
    -timeout 30
    "(current) UNIX password: " {
        # Password has expired
        send $password\r
        expect {
            "New password: " {
                send $new_password\r
                exp_continue
            }
            "Retype new password: " {
                send $new_password\r
                exp_continue
            }
            "all authentication tokens updated successfully." {
                # Password has been changed
            }
            default {
                error "Failed to change the password"
            }
        }
    }
    "assword: " {
        # Old password was not accepted
        send $new_password\r
        expect {
            -timeout 30
            -ex "~]$" {
                # New password was accepted
            }
            "assword: " {
                # New password was not accepted either
                error "None of the passwords was accepted"
            }
            default {
                error "Failed to log in"
            }
        }
    }
    "locked" {
        # Account is locked
    }
    -ex "~]$" {
        # Logged in with old password
        send "echo -e '$password\n$new_password\n$new_password' | passwd\r"
        expect {
            -ex "~]$" {
                # Password successfully updated
            }
            default {
                error "passwd command failed"
            }
        }
    }
    default {
        error "Log in timed out"
    }
}
close
```

That would be the basic structure. If it doesn't quite work, add an `exp_internal 1` command to determine which tweaks would be needed.

Comment: problem is now, it actually isn't executing that passwd command on second host with the account being fine...

so it rotates the first one, handling the expiry part, logs into next server, doesnt execute command and then timeout hits and the session closes.

Comment: it actually worked, when i pulled the passwd command outside the first expect, but left off the last exp_continue

Comment: I am also trying to set up another expect in this nest for logging in and the password already being changed....so login with current password -- get access denied, log it and move on through my iteration

Comment: If you pull the passwd command outside the first expect, you will try to change the password again on a server where you have just changed it due to expiry. That will fail, although your script will continue because it doesn't check for that. Having the command inside the first expect should work. But it is hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing an example of such a login attempt. Maybe it takes more than 10 seconds to get the shell prompt?

Comment: it worked moving it back out.  
the last part I need to implement, is if the password has already been changed and is using the new password.
i segmented this portion out and am trying to test it separately, 
`#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set user userAccount
set password oldPassword
set new_password newPassword
set f [open "input.txt"]
set hosts [read $f]
close $f
foreach host $hosts {
 spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
 expect "Password:" 
 send "$password\r"
 expect "Access denied"
 {close}
}`

Comment: You indicate that my solution to the first part of your problem doesn't work. That means I don't have a correct picture of your situation. If you are unwilling to pursue that any further, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you with any follow up questions.

Comment: Well, I thought that solution worked. Turns out it did not. So, I have what you showed above currently. It logs in to the host that has not expired and is not executing the passwd command it appears. Handling the expired accounts fine.

Comment: `expect { 
    "(current) UNIX password:" {send $password\r; exp_continue}
    "New password:" {send $new_password\r; exp_continue}
    "Retype new password:" {send $new_password\r}
    "~]$" {send "echo -e '$password\n$new_password\n$new_password' | passwd\r"}
}
expect "~]$" {close}
`
I do not know why this wont align...

Comment: Additionally, I am having a real troublesome time finding info on correctly using the log_file and send_log functions within Expect. All I am trying to do is log when the text "All authentication tokens updated successfully" and then append the name of the host to that...so far to no avail.

Comment: I added a second part to my answer to be able to provide formatted code for your additional requests.

Comment: The log_file command is intended to log a transcript of the session to a file. If you just want to have a log file with a line for each successfully updated host, you would be better off using the Tcl commands open and puts. E.g.:
    `set log [open logfile a]`
and
    `puts $log "All authentication tokens updated successfully for $host"`

Comment: where would you add the exp_internal 1? errors out at the default { error "Failed to log in"}

Comment: The exp_internal 1 goes before the part you want to investigate. For the "Failed to log in" error I would put it just after the "Old password was not accepted" comment. You can also put it at the start of the script, but then you'll have to dig through more debugging output.

Comment: Failed to change the password
    while executing
"error "Failed to change the password""
    invoked from within
"expect {
                    "New password:" {
                    send $new_password\r
                    exp_continue
                    }
                    "Retype new password:"..."
    invoked from within
"expect {
            -timeout 30
            "(current) UNIX password:" {
                # Password has expired
                send $password\r
                expect {
                    "..."

Comment: ("foreach" body line 5)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
        spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
        expect "Password:"
        send "$password\r"
        expect {
            -t..."
    (file "./PasswordChange.exp" line 19)

Comment: Last two comments are the error. So the test file i gave it had two hosts where the password has already been rotated and one where the account is expired -- seemed to handle everything fine -- logging into already rotated hosts and logging out....

Comment: Then my best guess is that the shell prompt is different from "~]$". But like I suggested before, check the debugging output from `exp_internal 1`. It's impossible for me to come up with a definitive answer without knowing the exact input or seeing that output.

Comment: all the same prompt...where is the output saved? I do not see it in the cygwin terminal...perhaps home dir on the server?

Comment: The output generated from `exp_internal 1` goes to the standard error channel (stderr).

Comment: do not see these diagnostics...do i need to redirect stderr to a file ... i thouoght this would work..

`"Password:" {
                 # New password was not accepted either
                 error "None of the passwords were accepted"
                 exp_internal -f passwordRotation.log 1
             }`

Comment: Your exp_internal command is never executed. The error command stops any further command interpretation. Also, you won't get any useful data if you only start logging after the problem has already occurred.

Comment: here is the output from after attempting to log into last host; i realize it is messy -- at first glance i did not see anything glaring

Comment: `user@last_hosts's password: 
expect: does "user@last_host's password: " (spawn_id exp9) match glob pattern "Password:"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "oldPassword\r" to { exp9 }

expect: does "user@last_host's password: " (spawn_id exp9) match glob pattern "(current) UNIX password:"? no
"Password:"? no
"locked"? no
"~]$"? no


expect: does "user@last_host's password: \r\n" (spawn_id exp9) match glob pattern "(current) UNIX password:"? no
"Password:"? no
"locked"? no
"~]$"? no
user@last_host's password:`

Comment: `expect: does "user@last_host's password: \r\nuser@last_host's password: " (spawn_id exp9) match glob pattern "(current) UNIX password:"? no
"Password:"? no
"locked"? no
"~]$"? no
`

Comment: `expect: timed out
Log in timed out
    while executing
"error "Log in timed out""
    invoked from within
"expect {
     -timeout 30
     "(current) UNIX password:" {
         # Password has expired
         send $password\r
         expect {
             "..."
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
 exp_internal -f passwordRotation.log 1
 spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
 expect "Password:..."
    (file "./RHELPasswordChange.exp" line 19)`

Comment: Very glaring: The server sends "password:" (lowercase p), while your script expects "Password:" (uppercase P). This is why you frequently see `expect "assword:"` being used in scripts.  But this leads to "Log in timed out", not "Failed to log in" or "Failed to change the password", as you reported before.

Comment: ok. was thinking of switching to "assword:" based on some stuff i read. thanks schelte.

Comment: Getting errors now for Expired Accounts -- here it is with the input file with only an expired host.

Comment: `password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
expect: does " \r\nChanging password for user.\r\n(current) UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp5) match exact string "~]$"? no
"assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\nChanging password for user.\r\n(current) UNIX password:"
None of the passwords were accepted
    while executing
"error "None of the passwords were accepted""
    invoked from within
`

Comment: `"expect {
             -timeout 30
             -ex "~]$" {
                 # New password was accepted
             }
             "assword:" {
     ..."
    invoked from within
"expect {
     -timeout 30
     "(current) UNIX Password:" {
         # Password has expired
         send $password\r
         expect {
             "..."
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
 exp_internal -f passwordRotation.log 1
 spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
 expect "assword:"..."`

Comment: `(file "./RHELPasswordChange.exp" line 19)`

Comment: I suspect you didn't change all occurrences of "Password" to "assword". I have adapted the code in my answer. I also see again new case mismatches in your code "(current) UNIX Password:" versus "(current) UNIX password:". But anyway, I've given you the basic tools to make this work. Now you have to start thinking for yourself again.

Comment: schelte, thank you for all the help. script is working well, i have the logging working well....only issue is it seems to error out after an expired account and is usually due to one of the default error lines --

Comment: `asswd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "New password: "? no
"Retype new password: "? no
"~]$"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\npasswd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.\r\n"
Failed to change the password
    while executing
`

Comment: `"error "Failed to change the password""
    invoked from within
"expect {
                    "New password: " {
                        send $new_password\r
                        exp_continue
                    }
                    "Retype new p..."
    invoked from within
"expect {
            -timeout 30
            "(current) UNIX password: " {
                # Password has expired
                send $password\r
               `

Comment: `expect {
                    ..."
    ("foreach" body line 7)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
        exp_internal 1
        set log [open "passwordRotation.log" a]
        spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
        ..."
    (file "./RHELPasswordChange.exp" line 19)`

Comment: I expected that after you changed the password on an expired login, you would get the prompt. But apparently the server closes the connection. So, instead of looking for the prompt, you could look for "all authentication tokens updated successfully."

Comment: makes sense, good catch, i think on some servers it closes connection, some it stays open. thanks again.

Comment: Schelte, it is again working really well, so thank you for that. but randomly erroring out again:

Comment: `parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {30560}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp65) match glob pattern "assword: "? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp65"
`

Comment: `expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
send: sending "oldPassword\r" to { exp65 send: spawn id exp65 not open
    while executing
"send "$password\r""
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
        exp_internal 1
        set log [open "passwordRotation.log" a]
        spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
        ..."
    (file "./RHELPasswordChange.exp" line 19)`

Comment: seems like it is just getting out of sync, but i havent been able to identify what is going -- the log output for the host is fine -- already using new password...

Comment: also it never disconnects from server, so its hung on something

Comment: `$ ./RHELPasswordChange.exp
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {50588}
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "assword: "? no
Password:
expect: does "Password:" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "assword: "? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "oldPassword\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does "Password:" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "(current) UNIX password: "? no
"assword: "? no
"locked"? no
"~]$"? no`

Comment: `expect: does "Password:\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "(current) UNIX password: "? no
"assword: "? no
"locked"? no
"~]$"? no
Password:
expect: does "Password:\r\nPassword:" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "(current) UNIX password: "? no
"assword: "? no
"locked"? no
"~]$"? no
expect: timed out
Log in timed out
    while executing
"error "Log in timed out""
    invoked from within
"expect {`

Comment: `-timeout 30
            "(current) UNIX password: " {
                # Password has expired
                send $password\r
                expect {
                    ..."
    ("foreach" body line 7)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
        exp_internal 1
        set log [open "passwordRotation.log" a]
        spawn -noecho /bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
        ..."
    (file "./RHELPasswordChange.exp" line 19) `

Comment: so, again, its not passing the new password here, i thought it was an issue with the prompt -- this host's prompt is "$" but when i changed to that this host still errored out all the same..